# Only try to define pulse audio remap sink when master device exists?

Tags: audio, pulse-audio

I have a custom pulse audio rule in my `default.pa`:

```
.nofail
load-module module-remap-sink \
  sink_name=MyRemapSink \
  master=alsa_output.some.device.path # settings ...
.fail
```

When I enable JACK, I see some errors popping up, as PA can no longer see the original device (just the JACK sink), and so cant define the remap sink.

There is a syntax rule `.ifexists` but that seems to be specifically for files.

Is there a way to stop pulse audio from trying to define my remap sink if the device isn't there?